# PHP: Parent Class and a Child Class

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am trying to learn more about OOP in PHP so I setup a simple situation.

I have a MySQL database that holds a table with wallets. Then I made the following class:

```
class WalletConnection {

    private $db;
    private $user_id;
    private $wallets;

    public function __construct ($user_id) {

        $this->user_id = $user_id;
        $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ws;charset=utf8', 'dbuser', '***');
        $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    }

    public function loadWallets () {

        $sql = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id, CurrencyCode, Balance FROM wallets WHERE UserID = :UserID');
        $sql->execute([':UserID' => $this->user_id]);
        $this->wallets = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    }

    public function getWallet ($num) {

        // do something like: new Wallet($this->wallets[$num])

    }

}
```

Then I create the wallet connection like this:

```
$wallets = new WalletConnection(40); // 40 = UserID of wallet owner
$wallets->loadWallets();
```

Now I want to create a child class Wallet to work with individual wallets.

```
class Wallet extends WalletConnection {

    private $id, $balance, $currency_code;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->id = $data['id'];
        $this->balance = $data['Balance'];
        $this->currency_code = $data['CurrencyCode'];
    }

    public function getBalance() {
    }

}
```

To learn more about OOP I want to build this:

```
$wallet = $wallets->getWallet(0); // This will now contain the id, CurrencyCode, Balance of the first wallet of the parent's $wallets.
```

So I think I need to add a getWallet() function to the WalletConnection class and call "new Wallet" from there.

And then in the client code I want to do:

```
$wallet->getBalance()
```

At the moment I don't know if I am doing this the right way, and if I am I need to know what to do next to make sure that for example the getBalance() function can use the parent's $db connection.

Comment: Sure, instantiating a new wallet by `new Wallet` in the `getWallet()` method does make sense. You then return that wallet to the outside scope. Just fine. However you want to "cache" that object in the `$wallets` object in case it is called a second time. You do _not_ want to create a second object in that case, I assume. You can define an property in the `WalletConnection` class for that. If that already holds an object for a specific index, then return that, otherwise instantiate, cache and return a new one.

Comment: Ok but when I call a function from getBalance() to run a sqlQuery inside the Parent, then $this becomes the "Child's" $this, so $this->db becomes unavailable. I don't want to create a new connection for every wallet.

Comment: Well, you can either "inject" the database object into the wallet object via the constructor, or, more elegant, you store a back reference to the WalletCollection in the Wallets, that way you can use that objects database connection inside the Wallet object.

Comment: I tried that last part with a simple (non database) example. To WalletConnection I added: protected function getUserID () { return $this->user_id; } -- Now if I call $this->getUserID() from the Wallet (child) then it's empty, because $this in the parent's getUserID() is now the child's $this() and not the parent's.

Comment: Wah, sorry, I did not pay attention. Your issue is that you actually derive the `Wallet` class from the `WalletConnection` class which does not really make sense. The `WalletConnection` implements a set of things, but a Wallet implements one specific of those things. So they describe completely different semantic meanings. So why would you want to extend `Wallet` from `WalletConnection`?

Comment: I want to use WalletConnection to connect to the database and get lists of all wallets, and the ability to select a "current wallet". This current wallet should be the child "Wallet" that has functions like getBalance, or updateBalance and uses the WalletConnection for this. Or do you think it's better to not use a child at all and keep it all in WalletConnection?

Comment: I _think_ I understood what you say and I _think_ I did not say something against it. Certainly each wallet should be represented by its own object, so you need a `Wallet` class. What I question is if that class should extend the `WalletConnection` class, since I do not see any sense in that. Those are different things. A class should only be extended if you implement a specialized variant of the same thing. To me you should have two separate classes.

Comment: Alright, the reason I wanted to extend WalletConnection is so I can use its database connection. If Wallet is on its own then every wallet I create needs to connect to the database itself?

Comment: No! I said so above: either you inject (hand over) the database object from the WalletConnection into each instantiated Wallet object (by handing it over to the constructor), or you hand over a back reference to the WalletManager which allows to use that connection object. Go with the first option for now to keep things simple.

Comment: Much more elegant would even be not to instantiate the database object inside the WalletColletion (since the database connection is not a specific details of the Collection but general purpose to your application), but use a singleton pattern to maintain a global database object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to learn more about OOP start by learning the principals of it.
http://codebetter.com/raymondlewallen/2005/07/19/4-major-principles-of-object-oriented-programming/

You should dive deep into the **Encapsulation** principal specifically since you have violated it here by making a dependency between your DB and your Wallet.

A better practice would be to make a wallet as model, and a service which is in charge of the functionality related to it (such as getWalletById).

You would want a mapper that knows how to take the information from the database (usually array) and maps it to the wallet model.

Also you want to use an adapter that can connect to the database and NOT just work with wallets.

Remember that extending is not always the solution, sometimes you should use use composition over inheritance.

For example, the service contains a mapper, and the mapper contains the adapter.

To sum things up, try something like this:

1. Create a wallet model. Create a wallet service. Create a wallet
   mapper. Create a PDO adapter.
2. Use the PDO Adapter to get the raw SQL wallet data
3. Map the array to the proper wallet model and return it through the mapper
4. Return the Wallet model through the service.

In the end you should have a single line of code:

```
$wallet = $walletService->getWalletById($id);
```

And you should be able to use its attributes by being public or by a getter:

```
$balance = $wallet->balace;
```

or

```
$balance = $wallat->getBalance();
```